# Where can I find good ground sumac?

Tags: spices

An Iranian friend once gave me some ground sumac to eat with a meal.  I loved its tangy,clean taste.  I later bought some online, but there was no tangy taste.  Tried an import store with the same result.  Would like to find the good stuff.

Comment: You may want to consider sharing your general location. It'll help other users give more accurate recommendations.

Comment: just make sure not to use poison sumac as that could get very itchy!!! ;P

Answer (score 6):

As with almost anything you can purchase ground, you can also purchase sumac berries whole:

[image: 1]

You may be able to buy them whole locally, you can certainly buy them whole online, as that picture is from Amazon. Spices lose their flavor quickly once ground, it's almost always better to grind your own.

If you don't have a spice grinder, I recommend checking out local thrift stores for a used, rotary style coffee grinder. Even new, they're very inexpensive, and then you'll always be able to grind your own spices.

Answer (score 2):

My neighbor grows it (in Colorado no less).  My local spice shop also carries a very nice sumac.